# Make plot to start at 0

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

How to make lines start at 0, when plotting a matrix using the `plot` function?

To be more precise, this is what I want to solve:
[image]

Comment: Code please? And simple, just have a value for x and y at x=0 in your plot call

Comment: Using x-data that starts from 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [help](http://www.mathworks.it/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) for the `plot` command: When using the plot command with a single argument, Matlab implicitly plots the argument versus its index, so `plot([3,5,9])` is equivalent to `plot([1,2,3], [3,5,9])`. More in general, `plot(y)` corresponds to `plot(1:length(y), y)` for a vector and `plot(M)` corresponds to `plot(1:size(M, 1), M)` for a matrix.

To plot starting from zero, you should thus do `plot(0:length(y) - 1, y)` for vectors, or  `plot(0:size(M, 1) - 1, M)` for matrices, as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with "xlim" will be enought.

It this case you can just write:

```
xlim([0,32]);
```

In a more generic case you might need to use:

```
a1=min(x);
a2=max(x);

xlim([a1,a2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and I resolved it by changing the **Y-scale** **to 'linear' from 'log'.**
On figure window navigate Edit-> Axes Properties... Then select Y-axis and change the Y-scale to 'linear'.

Comment: This should not affect the `x`-axis at all, so I doubt it is an answer to the question.